# splitByChar Nullable

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have the next query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col_name, toTypeName(col_name)
  FROM remote('host_name', 'db.table', 'user', 'password')
```

The result is a 6 records(`WITHOUT NULL`). Example:

```
some_prefix-1, Nullable(String)
...
some_prefix-6, Nullable(String)
```

Now I try **splitByChar**, but I'm getting:

> Code: 43, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Nested type Array(String)
>   cannot be inside Nullable type (version 20.1.2.4 (official build))

I tried to use `not null condition` and convert type but the problem still remains. Like that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT toString(col_name) AS col_name_str,
                splitByChar('-', col_name_str)
  FROM remote('host_name', 'db.table', 'user', 'password')
 WHERE col_name IS NOT NULL
```

Is this expected behavior? How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lack of Nullable support in splitByChar (https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/6517)

You use wrong cast `toString`

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    cast(col_name, 'String') AS col_name_str,
    splitByChar('-', col_name_str)
FROM
(
    SELECT cast('aaaaa-vvvv', 'Nullable(String)') AS col_name
)
WHERE isNotNull(col_name)

┌─col_name_str─┬─splitByChar('-', cast(col_name, 'String'))─┐
│ aaaaa-vvvv   │ ['aaaaa','vvvv']                           │
└──────────────┴────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

or `assumeNotNull`

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    assumeNotNull(col_name) AS col_name_str,
    splitByChar('-', col_name_str)
FROM
(
    SELECT cast('aaaaa-vvvv', 'Nullable(String)') AS col_name
)
WHERE isNotNull(col_name)

┌─col_name_str─┬─splitByChar('-', assumeNotNull(col_name))─┐
│ aaaaa-vvvv   │ ['aaaaa','vvvv']                          │
└──────────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────┘
```